# No such file or directory:

Tags: python, pandas

Мой код:

```
file = './Нет вложений.xlsx' #---- указываем путь к файлу
excel_data = pandas.read_excel(file, usecols=cols)
```

Запуская, выводится такая ошибка:

```
 handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Нет вложений.xlsx'
```

Хотя такой  файл у меня имеется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пути файлов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте удалить ./

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Вам нужен относительный или полный путь?

Comment: Убедитесь, что рабочая директория та же папка, где файл. Вообще, узнать путь, по котором будет поиск просто: `import os` + `print(os.path.abspath('./Нет вложений.xlsx'))`. Скорее всего, у вас будет другой путь. Тогда вам или указывать рабочую папку (например, если из консоли запускаете), или из самого скрипта получить текущую папку (https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/eee30c561c5e547bc4885d73dd9e1bd68a739370/config.py#L11) и от нее построить путь к файлу

Comment: Как вы запускаете скрипт?

Comment: @CrazyElf, Запускаю скрипт через Shift + F10

Comment: @AlAvenger, Мне неважно какой путь будет, главное что бы видео файл

Comment: @gil9red, в вопрос дополнил пути файлов.

Comment: Скопируйте путь до папки и допишите название файла (например ```C:\\MyDir\\Нет вложений.xlsx```)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по второму скриншоту и SHift-F10, у Вас PyCharm.

Установите "правильный" стартовый каталог

Run->Edit Configuration->Working Directory